Using generics with nestJs/Swagger utility functions
I use @nestJs/swagger package to create my DTOs for my project, and when I tried to use generics with it I faced the following issue in classes C and D when passing the generic T to class A: TS2562: Base class expressions cannot reference class type parameters.
import { IsString } from '@nestjs/class-validator';
import { IntersectionType, PickType } from '@nestjs/swagger';

class A<T> {
  fieldOne: T;
  fieldTwo: string;
}

class B {
  @IsString()
  fieldThree: string;
}

class C<T> extends IntersectionType(A<T>, B) {}

class D<T> extends PickType(A<T>, ['fieldOne']) {}

I use this package (@nestJs/swagger) to ensure that all the annotations from @nestjs/class-validator (or from @nestjs/class-transformer) are kept during execution.
I would say that I'm running the latest version of nestJs  with the following packages installed (I filtered out the irrelevant packages):
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "@nestjs/class-validator": "^0.13.4",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    ...
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    ...
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }

